# Priority of grammar, spelling and punctuation in questions

Tags: discussion, edits, ethics

How much priority should be given to grammar, spelling and punctuation when editing a question? How relevant are those? Should questions and answers be edited because of the sole reason there are spelling/grammatical errors?